# React App Crashes When a certain Component Rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-translate, google-translation-api

To be honest, I don't know what really causes the problem but will try to explain it.
In my react app, I have placed a Google Translate Widget (which is retired some years ago) to easily translate whole website in just a click. It works fine until I am clicking on a MODAL or some button that changes TAB without changing routes. I mean, when routing there is no problem but if new component renders in the same route (like it does in MODAL and TAB component), the app crashes and all I am getting is a blank page.
Images to make it clearer:

[image]

As it seems, Google translated page to French in homepage here is a different route and everything seems OK.
BUT when I click on Make a Reservation Button (which is the vertical one) or All Features button (which is the black one at the bottom), distressingly this is what I get:
[image]

A blank page. So, without using google-translate-widget all is working without a problem. But if the page is translated and user clicks on a button renders some component on the same route this happens. ANY solution suggestion or comment means so much to me.
Thank you.

Comment: What console says?

Comment: 1- "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node."           2- "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the component which cause the insertBefore error inside span tag. It solved the issue.

Comment: Did google translate cause the issue?

Comment: Yes, it caused the issue.